# Rserve fails to set up connection

Tags: rserve

Up to yesterday, I have been connecting Tableau with R through Rserve on my localhost. Today, when I try to make the connection again, Tableau complained:

> a error occurred during connection to localhost: 6311. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I doubled check Rserve is running. However, when I typed `telnet localhost 6311` in cmd, no connection can be detected. It strikes me that something worked well for a few months suddenly stopped to function. I did installed RMySQL yesterday which seem to coincide with the timing, but is it possible? Any idea how to trouble shoot? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple things might be happening here.

1. check your netstat -ntlp output and see if its' listening on port 6311 and check if it's listening at 0.0.0.0:6311 or 127.0.0.1:6311. If you use the hostname rather than localhost it should be able to connect as long as the deamon is up. To connect using localhost from the same machine, stop Rserve and restart it as R CMD Rserve this will bind it to the loopback address, if you want it remotely accessible then you'll have to restart it using R CMD Rserve --RS-enable-remote
2. If you are using linux, you'll need to check your firewall and see if port 6311 is allowed .... ufw allow 6311 will do the trick.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/r-implementation-notes) explanation may be helpful.

In my case, I was running through 'Rserve' and the configuration did not allow remote.

Answer (score 0):

Initially invoke the Rserve using the command R CMD Rserve --RS-enable-remote from your server.Then call Rserve from your client machine.To test the connection try telnet IP port to the server which runs Rserve.This will do the trick.